# Question about counting elements in a set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am currently reading some theory about distribution of primes. There is a claim that says, infinite subsets come in different shapes and sizes. For example, the sets $G=\{2^n: n=1,2,3,.. \}$, $Q=\{n^2: n=1,2,3,.., \}$ and $E=\{2n: n=1,2,3,...,\}$ are all infinite subsets of N, but they have distinctly different natures if you consider their respective counting functions $N_G(x)=\#\{ n \in G: n\leq x\}$,  $N_Q(x)=\#\{n \in Q:n \leq x\}$, $N_E(x)= \#\{n \in E: n \leq x\}$. Why is the following true?: $N_G(x) \approx log_2(x)$, $N_Q(x) \approx x^{0.5}$. $N_E(x) \approx x/2$

Another way of seeing the difference in the sizes of these sets is by considering the sums of the reciprocals of elements from each set. For the set G, this is a geometric series.

$$S_G(N)= \sum_{m \in G, m \leq N}1/m= \sum_{n=1}^{log_2(N)}1/2^n=1-1/2^{log_2(N)}=1-1/N$$

For this geometric series, I am considering the expression $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}r^k=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$ I don't know how they got to the latter result by using this expression

Comment: About the sum of reciprocals: Are you supposed to sum over the whole set or are you supposed to just taking a finite sum?

Comment: I think it's a finite sum hence $m \leq N$

Comment: I forgot to say that here they are assuming $N=2^n$, for some $n \in N$

Comment: Re: Your last line : When $r=1/2$ we have $S_n=2-2^{-n}$. And  $\sum_{k=1}^n r^k=S_n-1,$ which when $ r=1/2, $  is  $ (2-2^{-n})-1=1-2^{-n}. $.... BTW  $1-1/N$ is an upper bound for  $S_G(N)$ and is not equal to $S_G(N)$ except when $N\in G, $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is the largest such $n$ such that $2^n \leq x$, then $n \leq \log_2(x)$.  So $N_G(x)=\lfloor \log_2(x) \rfloor$

If $n$ is the largest such $n$ such that $n^2 \leq x$, then $n \leq \sqrt{x}$.  So $N_Q(x)=\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$

If $n$ is the largest such $n$ such that $2n \leq x$, then $n \leq x/2$.  So $N_E(x)=\lfloor x/2 \rfloor $

---

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\log_2 (N)} 1/2^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\log_2 (N)} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n=\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)\sum_{n=0}^{\log_2 (N)-1} \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n=\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\log_2(N)-1+1}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)}=$$ $$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\log_2(N)}}{\frac{1}{2}}=1-\frac{1}{2^{\log_2(N)}}=1-\frac{1}{N} $$

We are considering the sum of the reciprocals because $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty$$

while $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}} < \infty$$

no matter how small $\epsilon > 0$ is.  Summing over subsets can give us a feel for the frequency of the elements.

Comment: Of course.  If my answer was helpful, it would be nice if you accepted it by clicking on the checkmark

Comment: Sure, I did it already. I have another question, so if you can , check my thread.

Comment: @TheMathNoob Well I see that I got a "like", but to "accept" an answer, you need to click on the checkmark.  The checkmark is right under the arrows next to my answer.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh got it

Comment: So if the function is not sparse at all, for example y=n, then the series converges to infinity?

Comment: @TheMathNoob Diverge to infinity, yes.  This includes sets of multiples of any given positive integer (in particular, the even numbers).